# How to convert xml file which is in non UTF-8 format to xml that is UTF-8 compliant

Tags: linux, shell, unix, unicode, utf-8

I have a huge xml file whose sample data is as follows :

```
 <vendor name="aglaia"><br>
              <vendorOUI oui="000B91" description="Aglaia Gesellschaft fÃ¼r Bildverarbeitung ud Kommunikation m" /><br>
         </vendor><br>
         <vendor name="ag"><br>
              <vendorOUI oui="0024A9" description="Ag Leader Technology" /><br>
         </vendor><br>
```

as it can be see there are text " Gesellschaft fÃ¼r Bildverarbeitung " which is not UTF-8 compliant because which I am getting errors from the xml validator , errors like:

```
Import failed:
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

So the query is how to take care of this in Linux environment to convert the xml file to UTF-8 compliant format? or is there a way in bash such that while creating the xml in the first place i can ensure that all variables/strings are stored in UTF-8 compliant format?

Comment: Does the current XML header specify the encoding?  I.e. is there a header like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and if so, what is the encoding?  If the file does not have this header, do you know the actual encoding?

Comment: this is the header that is added by my script while creating the xml, but as i said its just echoed into the xml::<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <vendors>

Comment: The real question is the XML generated is valid or not, based on this you have to change the XML generator or use a generic XML parsing library that is able to deal with valid encodings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the character set conversion tool:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 filename.txt
```

See [gnu-page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html)

...and in file http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt "aglia" (as in your example above) is reported as:

```
00-0B-91   (hex)            Aglaia Gesellschaft für Bildverarbeitung und Kommunikation m
000B91     (base 16)        Aglaia Gesellschaft für Bildverarbeitung und Kommunikation m
                            Tiniusstr. 12-15
                            Berlin  D-13089
                            GERMANY
```

it seems like "ü" is the character that gets mangeld.

**Update**

When downloading "oui.txt" using wget, I see the character "ü" in the file. If you don't have that something is broken in your download. consider using one of these:

- `wget --header='Accept-Charset: utf-8'`
- try using `curl -o oui.txt` instead

If none of the above works, just open the link in you favorite browser and do a "save as". In that case, comment the `wget` line in the script below.

I had success with the following script (update BEGIN & END to get a valid XML-file)

```
#!/bin/bash

wget http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt
iconv -f iso-8859-15 -t utf-8 oui.txt > converted

awk 'BEGIN {
         print "HTML-header"
     }

     /base 16/ {
         printf("<vendor name=\"%s\">\n", $4)
         read
         desc = substr($0, index($0, $4))
         printf("<vendorOUI oui=\"%s\" description=\"%s\"/>\n", $1, desc)
     }
     END {
         print "HTML-footer"
    }
    ' converted
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That assumes the current codepage is ISO-8859-1, which it may not be.

Comment: @Nosib what does `file filename.txt` output?

Comment: @Fredrik : I have a file vendor.xml whose encoding i am not sure about which has to be converted to a UTF-8 compliant file , so my usage as per your advice is  iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8  vendor.xml hope that answers what you are asking

Comment: The encoding format is also what is used in http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt , because my basic input file is this. So can we find out the encoding format used here?

Comment: You can't convert it to uft-8 unless you know what encoding the file is in now. You need to get ahold of the people or program that generated it and find out what encoding was in effect. If it really is 8859-1, fine. If you just guess that it's 8859-1 and you guess wrong, you're making a bigger mess.

Comment: The file is posted in http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt so whats the option out , coz i doubt they would reply none the less i have mailed them..is there an alternative?

Comment: `file` reports oui.txt as ASCII

Comment: I am parsing the oui.txt file by a bash script to generate the xml during which i am getting the xml as < vendor name="aglaia">
< vendorOUI oui="000B91" description="Aglaia Gesellschaft fÃ¼r Bildverarbeitung ud Kommunikation m" />
< /vendor>
< vendor name="ag">
< vendorOUI oui="0024A9" description="Ag Leader Technology" />
< /vendor>

Comment: type `locale` at you prompt and post output here (should be utf-8). Should be trivial to create the xml-file from oui.txt using python. I can do it tomorrow if you haven't solved it by then. Well past midnight now and my wife hate me when doing SO late ;-)

Comment: This is what it looks like after i download the file using wget :00-0B-91   (hex)                Aglaia Gesellschaft fÃ¼r Bildverarbeitung und Kommunikation m
000B91     (base 16)            Aglaia Gesellschaft fÃ¼r Bildverarbeitung und Kommunikation m
                                Tiniusstr. 12-15
                                Berlin  D-13089
                                GERMANY

Comment: locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
Thanks for the help!!! Hope you could give a break through tomorrow with a bash script..

Comment: Thanks a bunch Fredrik for going out your way to help!!! sincere gratitude at your support. I modified the xml parser to take care of it...so thankyou once again.